# Solution for 20Vpp output waveform opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am planning to design an opamp circuit from 2Vpp to 40 Vpp for frequency rage 0-5MHz as shown in the Figure:

[image: opamp design circuit]

The problem I am facing right now is in the market, there is not an opamp chip that can amplify up to 40Vpp, because the Vmax total voltage supply from V+ to V- for opamp at 5MHz is around  26V, that means V+ =18V only, therefore my output amplitude will be clipped off when V=16V, so how to achieve it? Any possible solution can recommend?

Comment: Do you mean to say V+ to V- = 36V ?

Comment: V+ =18V and V- =18V..

Comment: Do you mean 20v peak to peak or 40v peak to peak? There are plenty of op-amps that can do 20Vp-p.

Comment: Can you give some detail of the application where you are willing to use -20V signal?

Comment: OPA452, OPA453, LM143, LM343 could be used.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Please use the `edit` button below your question and fix the errors and inconsistencies. For example, you say you want to amplify 1Vpp to 20Vpp, but the figure shows amplifying 2Vpp to 30Vpp.

Comment: @Andyaka,20 Vpeak to peak..

Comment: @AKR,but the slew rate and bandwidth is below to 10.. and for my amplifier circuit ,the slew rate should be at least 650V/us and bandwidth 200..

Comment: @DaveTweed,sorry for  the unclear, ya, I am planning to amplify 2 Vpp to 40 Vpp...as the output amplitude waveform up to 15V ,it will clipped off..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a discrete class AB output stage preceded by a class A with minimal voltage gain and fed from your opamp output. Minimizing the gain here (so that most of your gain is in your op-amp stage) will be necessary so that you are not bandwidth limited and slew-rate limited in your output stage.  You are operating at 5MHz so you will want at least a 10Mhz bandwidth, maybe somewhat more.  This will not be trivial.

You can operate your opamp at \$\pm 12\$V and swing it to \$\pm 10\$V , and then follow that with an A-AB amplifer stage with a gain of \$2\$V/V and powered from \$\pm 24\$V or so.

Here's a simplified view of an AB amplifier output stage.

[image]

This is an emitter follower (common collector) buffer amplifier and has no gain, actually, but you can precede it with a common emitter amplifier (class A) for your gain stage.

Something more like the following, although this one has two gain stages made up of Common Emitter amplifiers Q\$1\$ and Q\$2\$, and so it has too much gain for your needs (it has about x\$1600\$ gain... you want much less gain), meaning I am not proposing that you follow this exactly, it is a suggestion.

You will need to pick discrete transistors that can operate up to \$10\$Mhz or so, and make sure that your choice of R's and C's don't create low pass  (or high-pass) filters that limit your bandwidth.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting up a differential output. Have a 10V pk-pk waveform being generated which then feeds an inverter and a buffer. This will give you a differential output with 20V pk-pk swing

Added image:

[image]

Comment: may you elaborate more on inverter and buffer? as I only know purpose of inverter is invert the signal only, and then a buffer is a voltage follower?

Comment: img has been provided

Comment: the output from buffer isn't counteract the output from inverter?

Comment: Not if you treat it as a differential signal

Comment: but the supply of opamp just have 15V+ ,after differential,although the amplitude will be equal to 20 V, but it will clip off to just 15V+ right?